# Collector doesn't match wildcard in result type

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors

I have a List of data objects which I need to group in various ways, then perform common operations on the grouped results. So I am trying to extract the common operations to a single method, as in the following contrived example:

```
private static void print(List<Integer> data, 
                          Collector<Integer, ?, Map<?, List<Integer>>> collector) {
    data.stream().collect(collector)
            .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + list));
}

private static void printByMagnitude() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer,String>groupingBy(i -> i < 5 ? "small" : "large"));
}

private static void printByModulus() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer,Integer>groupingBy(i -> i % 2));
}
```

Note that in the `print` method, the collector's result type is a `Map` with unknown keys, `Map<?, List<Integer>>`, since when I print by magnitude I use `String` keys, and when I print by modulus I use `Integer` keys.

This code gives two compilation errors, on both calls to `Collectors.groupingBy`. The first complains about the call with `String` keys:

```
Error:(19, 58) java: incompatible types:
java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Integer,capture#1 of ?,
    java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>
cannot be converted to
java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Integer,?,
    java.util.Map<?,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>
```

The second complains about the call with `Integer` keys:

```
Error:(24, 59) java: incompatible types:     
java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Integer,capture#2 of ?,     
    java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>
cannot be converted to 
java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Integer,?,
    java.util.Map<?,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>
```

The return type of `Collectors.groupingBy` is `<T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>>`, so in the `Magnitude` and `Modulus` cases this should be

```
Collector<Integer, ?, Map<String,List<Integer>>>
Collector<Integer, ?, Map<Integer,List<Integer>>>
```

respectively.

Why don't these match the collector parameter in `print`,

```
Collector<Integer, ?, Map<?, List<Integer>>> collector
```

?

Comment: your method `printByModulus()` is being denyed by `print` method and rest is working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain with a simpler example, if you have a method `foo(Number)`, you can pass in an `Integer`, because `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`. However, if you have a method `foo(List<Number>)`, you can’t pass in a `List<Integer>`, because `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`.

But if your method `foo` only wants to retrieve `Number`s from the `List`, you might change the signature to `foo(List<? extends Number>)` (see also [“What is PECS”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488)), to allow lists being parametrized with a subtype of `Number`. `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`

Going to the more complex, both, `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>` and `Map<String,List<Integer>>`, are a subtypes of `Map<?,List<Integer>>`, but `Collector< … Map<Integer,List<Integer>> >` and `Collector< … Map<String,List<Integer>> >` are *not* subtypes of `Collector< … Map<?,List<Integer>> >`.

The solution is the same. You want to *retrieve* the map from the `Collector`, so you have to resort to “`? extends …`”, i.e. use the type `Collector<Integer, ?, ? extends Map<?, List<Integer>>>`:

```
private static void print(List<Integer> data, 
                      Collector<Integer, ?, ? extends Map<?, List<Integer>>> collector) {
    data.stream().collect(collector)
            .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + list));
}

private static void printByMagnitude() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer,String>groupingBy(i -> i < 5 ? "small" : "large"));
}

private static void printByModulus() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer,Integer>groupingBy(i -> i % 2));
}
```

Comment: Well-explained! I failed to account for the Map itself being a type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply write:

```java
private static <T, U> void print(List<T> data, 
        Collector<T, ?, Map<U, List<T>>> collector) {
    data.stream().collect(collector)
    .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + list));
}

private static void printByMagnitude() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer, String>groupingBy(i -> i < 5 ? "small" : "large"));
}

private static void printByModulus() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.<Integer, Integer>groupingBy(i -> i % 2));
}
```

The difference here is that I replaced the unbounded wildcard type (the '`?`' character) with generic parameters (I made the print method generic). The big difference is that the '`?`' unbounded wildcard type stands for *`one type`* of something not *`any type`* of something. Since you had two types of something (Integer and String), the compiler was complaining.

Also note that you don't really need to call the generic method with parameters (as of Java 7 I think). You can also simply write:

```java
private static <T, U> void print(List<T> data, 
        Collector<T, ?, Map<U, List<T>>> collector) {
    data.stream().collect(collector)
    .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + list));
}

private static void printByMagnitude() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i < 5 ? "small" : "large"));
}

private static void printByModulus() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    print(data, Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; making `print` a generic method does do the trick, but I was looking for a reason why the parameter wasn't matched as-is. See the accepted answer for a solution. Btw, you are correct that it is unnecessary to explicitly include the generic types in the method call. Doing this only helped clue the compiler into matching the `print` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I can't see how is that solution better? I gave you the answer why it isn't matched. Because '?' stands for one type of something, and you provide two types. That's the simplest answer you will ever get. Anyway, it's your choice. Happy coding!

Comment: Perhaps it's the wording, but your answer sounds as if only one of `String` or `Integer` should match `?`, which isn't true. The crux of my problem was in Collector's nested generic type. E.g. `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` both match `List<?>`, but neither `List<List<String>>` nor `List<List<Integer>>` match `List<List<?>>`. Those would only match `List<? extends List<?>>`.

Comment: No worries! I understand why you chose it. And that answer is a good answer also. And happy coding anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
private static <A, B> void print(List<Integer> data, Collector<Integer, ?, Map<A, List<B>>> groupingBy) {
        data.stream().collect(groupingBy).forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + value));
    }
```

with

```
private static void print(List<Integer> data, 
                          Collector<Integer, ?, Map<?, List<Integer>>> collector) {
    data.stream().collect(collector)
            .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + list));
}
```

**why?**

Because 
`?` holds true only for `Object` Class **ONLY and not even for its child classes**

ie

```
AnyType<?> object=new AnyType<Object> // true
AnyType<?> object=new AnyType<Number> // since Number is subchild of Object but Still false
```

EDIT :

In your method `printByModulus()` you are passing `Collectors.<Integer, Integer>` while in method `printByMagnitude()` you are passing `Collectors.<Integer, String>` is the only reason for your error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; making print a generic method does do the trick, but I was looking for a reason why the parameter wasn't matched as-is. See the accepted answer for a solution.

Comment: yes you are right but I wanted to draw your attention to point that `?` stands for `Object` class only when you use without `super` or `extends`

Comment: Not quite; try compiling your own example; `List<?> object = new ArrayList<Number>()` will work fine, because `Number` matches the wildcard `?`.